# Removable Bracket for Wood

Tags: wood, screws, brackets

I am hoping to bracket two pieces of wood together at in a removable fashion (parts of a table that can be disassembled).

Through research I found hanger bolts which look close to what I would want, but I think ideally I would have some sort of hollow screw into which a bolt could be threaded. That way I could screw into the wood once and then thread a bolt to attach the bracket when necessary.

Does this sort of part exist and if so what would be it's name?

Also is this a decent idea in general or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a "T Nut"?
[image]
Drill a hole for the central threaded part, then knock it in so the teeth grip & hold.